# Stealing something that could be considered offensive

Tags: halacha, current-events, gezel-stealing

Recently a [video](http://www.israelnationalnews.com/News/News.aspx/188391#.VIXdyMaIQds) has emerged of a man taking down a Palestinian flag in the neighbourhood of Meah Shearim, Jerusalem. There is no indication as to what happened to the flag after it was taken down. In any case, would one be allowed to steal an item that is deliberately provocative, potentially offensive and damaging to the achdut of Israel?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think doing so would be permitted?

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37454/5

Comment: Also similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1811/5

Comment: I would think that any nut that puts a Palestinian flag in a Jewish neighborhood is a Shoteh and thus unable to have ownership in the first place.

Comment: @GershonGold, I wouldn't put it past the Edah to put up Palestinian flags or other similar things due to their stance on M"Y. It could also have been put up by Neturei Karta, who have been known to do such shenanigans.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt It was in fact placed there by a Neturei Karta person. There's no way the Eidah HaCharedis would ever put up such a flag.

Comment: @Fred, I was unaware that the E"Ch was actually that sensitive on such issues, knowing the history of their leadership.

Answer (score 2):

Handing over somebody to the authorities is a very severe offense, called מּוֹסֵר.

Yet, one who endangers the public is allowed to be handed over to the authorities.

So one could call the cops (or the city) to get them to remove the flag.

As to whether one can confiscate his property: The Shulchan Aruch brings 2 opinions. Some forbid it, as it belongs to his heirs, others allow it if one keeps it (as opposed to destroying it.)

So it would seem there are opinions one could rely on to take the flag home foe safekeeping.

Source: Shulchan Aruch, [Choshen Mishpat סימן שפח](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01977_part_39.html):

> **יב** כָּל (מב) הַמּוֹסֵר הַצִּבּוּר **וּמְצַעֲרָן**, מֻתָּר לְמָסְרוֹ בְּיַד גּוֹיִים לְהַכּוֹתוֹ וּלְאָסְרוֹ **וּלְקָנְסוֹ**; אֲבָל מִפְּנֵי (מג) צַעַר יָחִיד אָסוּר לְמָסְרוֹ. **הגה**: (וְע''ל סִימָן תכ''ה ס''א) . מִי שֶׁעוֹסֵק בְּזִיּוּפִים וְכַדּוֹמֶה, **וְיֵשׁ לָחוּשׁ שֶׁיַּזִּיק רַבִּים**, מַתְרִין בּוֹ שֶׁלֹּא יַעֲשֶׂה, וְאִם אֵינוֹ מַשְׁגִּיחַ, **יְכוֹלִין לְמָסְרוֹ וְלוֹמַר שֶׁאֵין אַחֵר מִתְעַסֵּק בּוֹ אֶלָּא זֶה לְבַד**. מִי שֶׁרוֹצֶה לִבְרֹחַ וְלֹא לְשַׁלֵּם לַגּוֹי מַה שֶּׁחַיָּב, וְאַחֵר גִּלָּה הַדָּבָר, אֵין לוֹ דִּין מוֹסֵר, שֶׁהֲרֵי לֹא הִפְסִידוֹ רַק שֶׁהֻצְרַךְ לְשַׁלֵּם מַה שֶּׁחַיָּב, מִכָּל מָקוֹם בְּרָעָה עָשָׂה דְּהָוֵי כְּמֵשִׁיב אֲבֵדָה לְגוֹי; וְאִם גָּרַם לוֹ הֶזֵּק, חַיָּב לְשַׁלֵּם לוֹ מַה שֶּׁגָּרַם לוֹ (מַהֲרַ''ם מֵרִיזְבּוּרְק) . ‏
>
> **באר היטב**  (מב) **המוסר**. כן הוא בכל ספרי המחבר ובע''ש וטעות הוא וצ''ל המיצר וכן הוא בטור ורמב''ם. שם: (מג) **צער**. אבל במוסר ליחיד דינו כמוסר לצבור מיהו אפשר דלהרמב''ם דס''ל דאם כבר מסר אין הורגין אותו אא''כ הוחזק במוסר סבירא ליה דאם מוסר לצבור אפילו לא הוחזק מותר למסרו ביד אנסים. שם: ‏
>
> **יג** אָסוּר **לְאַבֵּד** (מד) **מָמוֹנוֹ שֶׁל מוֹסֵר** אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁמֻּתָּר לְאַבֵּד גּוּפוֹ, שֶׁהֲרֵי מָמוֹנוֹ רָאוּי לְיוֹרְשָׁיו. (וע''ל סי' ק''ח ס''ב) וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים (מה) **דְּמֻתָּר לִטֹּל מָמוֹנוֹ לְעַצְמ**וֹ, דְּאֵינוֹ אָסוּר אֶלָּא לְאַבְּדוֹ (מָרְדְּכַי פֶּרֶק הַגּוֹזֵל בַּתְרָא) . ‏
>
> **באר היטב**  (מד) **ממונו**. ביד אבל ע''י גרמא או גרמי מותר טור בשם העיטור ומהרי''ו סי' ק''ס ולמסור ממונו לאנסים אסור כן כת' מהרש''ל פרק הגוזל בתרא ס''ס נ' וע''ש ונראה דמי שמוחזק למסור ונראה שאין דבריו נשמעין רק מחמת עשרו וכשיעני לא יהיו דבריו נשמעין מותר לאבד ממונו או למוסרו לאנס שהרי במה שמאבדין ממונו מצילין אחרים ובתוס' דמסכתא ע''א דף כ''ו ע''ב נסתפקו אי משיבין אבידתו וכתבו דמסור גרוע ממומר לעבודת כוכבים ובכל מקום שונה מוסר אצל מין ולא אתרבי אצל אבידה ושמא מאן דאית ליה ממון מוסר אסור לאבדו ביד אית ליה נמי דמשיבין אבידתו ומטעמא דיכין רשע וצדיק ילבש עכ''ל ובהג''א ס''פ אלו מציאות כת' דמוסר הוי כמו מומר לעבודת כוכבים להכעיס דאסור להחזיר אבידתו ועיין שם: (מה) **דמותר**. והרי''ף וסייעתו בע''כ לא סבירא להו הכי וגם מהרש''ל שם פסק דאסור ליטול ממונו לעצמו וכן עיקר וכן משמע להדיא מתשובת רש''י שבמרדכי פ''ק דקדושין והביאה ב''י בסי' רפ''ג מחודש ב' ע''ש: ‏